# How to check for bad timestamping with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I am a beginner to gstreamer. When I create a pipeline to play a video file, I get the following message, "There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow". After some search I found that this problem might occur if there is a bad timestamping. Is there a way to figure out whether the video file has bad timestamps?

Here is the pipeline that I'm using,

gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=.mp4 ! qtdemux ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! dri2videosink.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert a identity element between e.g. ffdec_mpeg4 and drivideosink and use the check-imperfect-timestamp + check-imperfect-offset properties and watch the debug log.
If you work on an embedded device, watch the cpu load to see if maybe the pipeline runs indeed too slow.

Comment: I have checked cpu load and it is very normal. It takes only 0.1 % of CPU. I would use check-imperfect-timestamp property to check for bad timestamping. Thanks